# How to get selected String from Text

Tags: java

I try to get only this part "**10.135.57.1/24**" in "**10.135.57.1/24 05492518979**" in android. How can I do this?

I tried below to use substring but it can use for get integer How can I get only 10.135.57.1/24 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this string the following approach will work:

```
String[] parts = "10.135.57.1/24 05492518979".split(" ");
String partThatYouNeed = parts[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

In the substring method you're defining which subsection of the String you're after.

If you did the following you'd get your result:

```
String whatYouWant = "10.135.57.1/24 05492518979".substring(0, 14);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or using substring

```
String yourString = "10.135.57.1/24 05492518979";
int index = yourString.indexof(" ");
String partThatYouNeed = yourString.substring(0,index);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this :-)

```
"10.135.57.1/24 05492518979".replaceFirst(" \\d+$", "")
```

or this:

```
"10.135.57.1/24 05492518979".replaceFirst(" .+$", "")
```